# jQuery Script Not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this jQuery script but when you click the button it doesn't go along with what its supposed to.

I'm using the same script on a different button and it works.

Cant seem to find the issue D:

jQuery Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        var host = $("host").val();
        if(host != ""){
            $("#bootres").html("<p class='box'><img src='http://urgentbooter.com/img/ajax-loader.gif' border='0' alt='' /> Stopping attack...</p>");
            $.post("index.php?action=boot",{host:host,port:port,time:time,method:"STOP",submit:"submit2"},function(data){
        } else {
            alert("The host field must contain the IP to the attack you want to stop!");
            $("#host").focus();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Button Code:

```
<button type="button" id="stop" class="button red">Stop Attacks</button>
```

By the way the other button it works for is nearly the same code and its on the same page.

Let me know if more information is needed!

Comment: I put right after the click event handler and before the var host line  "alert('Test');" and it didn't work when you click the button, if that helps at all.

Comment: just a tip: try to see what errors are in your console. It will tell you a lot about this kind of mistakes! The answer of felix will solve the problem i think!

Comment: It shows on line 98 there is an unexpected token else, which is where it says else { alert("The host field".... etc..

Comment: That tells me that the problem is located before the else statement: see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you open the function here :

```
$.post("index.php?action=boot",{host:host,port:port,time:time,method:"STOP",submit:"submit2"},function(data){
```

this function is empty and not closed before the `else` keyword

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

```
var host = $("host").val();
```

to:

```
var host = $("#host").val();
```

You forgot to give `#` for targeting `id` here.

Comment: @user3023566 can you post the relevant HTML markup here? Currently you only show the button code.

Comment: Would you like me to make a jsFiddle?

Comment: Yes, it's even better :)

Comment: What does your console say?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with your code alignment.

Check your if block .

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#stop").click(function() {
        var host = $("#host").val();
        if(host != ""){
            $("#bootres").html("<p class='box'><img src='http://urgentbooter.com/img/ajax-loader.gif' border='0' alt='' /> Stopping attack...</p>");
            $.post("index.php?action=boot",{host:host,port:port,time:time,method:"STOP",submit:"submit2"},function(data){
            } );}

                   else {
            alert("The host field must contain the IP to the attack you want to stop!");
            $("#host").focus();
        }
    });
});
```